# Can I ask a question using photos?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, images, best-practices

Can I ask a question using photos?

Comment: Thank you for asking first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because several reasons but I have no words.

Comment: Some related older posts: [Are pictures of hand-written drawings allowed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12289) and [On the inclusion of pages-of-text-as-images in questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1805). Maybe also: [What should I do when I see a “pic-question”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677) and [Should I edit a question everytime I see an image in it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11696)

Answer (score 13):

We prefer you do not ask a question using a photo of text. Instead, please transcribe it using MathJax. There are several reasons for this.

1. Without text, the question is unsearchable, and it is unlikely another user with the same question will find it. The core principle of StackExchange is to provide help in a way that can also benefit spectators and future users.
2. We encourage long term participation here, which means integrating into the community, learning its norms, and participating in other ways than asking questions. To write good answers, you'll need to learn the basics of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), so now is as good of a time to learn as any! (The guide is very good.)
3. Lastly, some users feel that there should be a greater expectation of effort from the reader. Properly transcribing the question in a way that conforms to our [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) is considered a show of good faith.

With these things said, there is nothing wrong with including pictures with questions when they contribute additional meaning. Diagrams and drawings can be excellent supplements to a question (even if they are from a secondary source). It is important that they do not comprise the entire body of the question. When in doubt, explain your thoughts in your own words, that you wrote.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One other significant reason for trying to use text instead of a photo is to make it easier for visually impaired people using screen readers, e.g., as discussed in Meta in several posts such as [Stack Exchange policy on images and the visually impaired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337201/562482) and [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/562482).